# Populating React-Native ListView from JSON Data

Tags: ios, reactjs, listview

React-Native amateur here, I've written a php api to retrieve data from a MySQL server, and I need to put this into a ListView to display on an app.

The code for showing this is:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.response)
    };
  }

  renderRow(rowData) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.row}>
        <Text>{response}</Text>
        </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
      return {
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
      );
    }
  }
```

And the API json return is as follows:

```
[{"barcode":"50201600","name":"Cadbury's Creme 
Egg","tescoPrice":"1","sainsburysPrice":"1","asdaPrice":"1"},
{"barcode":"5034660520191","name":"Cadburys Twirl 4 
Pack","tescoPrice":"1","sainsburysPrice":"1","asdaPrice":"1"}]
```

The error I get is:`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {barcode, name, tescoPrice, sainsburysPrice, asdaPrice}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Check the render method of 'Text'`

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: What's the question ? What have you tried ? Is there any error message ? We are not here to do your homework for you...

Comment: @c4k I specified what I needed to do in the form of a question. I need to put the json data return from the API into a list view to show the products.

The error message shown is "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {barcode, name, tescoPrice, sainsburysPrice, asdaPrice})

 It's not homework, it's a personal project thanks! :)

Comment: What happens if you change `<Text>{response}</Text>` to `<Text>{response.name}</Text>` for example ?

Comment: @c4k same error unfortunately

Comment: Actually, what is the `response` variable in `renderRow()` ? Shouldn't it be `rowData.name` ?

Comment: @c4k I changed it to 'rowData.name' and got the same error

Comment: Well we are missing something then. Update the question with the full stack trace of the error with the line where it occurs.

Comment: In the code snipped you provided, you have only one `Text` component. How can you have the same error when doing what I said before ? Make sure you are editing the good file and saving it...

Comment: @c4k I have been editing the good file and save it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error i see, you need to change from:

```js
renderRow(rowData) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <Text>{response}</Text>
    </View>
 )
}
```

into something like:

```js
    renderRow(rowData) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>
        </View>
     )
    }
```

Comment: I still get the same Objects are not valid as a React child error for some reason

Comment: can you `console.log(rowData)` <-- what is the rowData

Comment: When I get the Objects are not valid as a React child error I cannot log anything from the file.